# How to do Phase Resolved Partial Discharge (PRPD) analysis using MATLAB and Simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I've been asked to simulate a model in Simulink for Phase Resolved Partial Discharge (PRPD) Analysis for an input signal and store the output data from the model in a file (in txt/csv/excel format), then use this data file to obtain scattered plot visualization of the PRPD analysis using MATLAB/Python code.

Comment: What is "Phase Resolved Partial Discharge (PRPD) Analysis"

Comment: @Pratyush, I would just search research papers for timevarying PRPD simulations